# Bus tours from Los Angeles to Grand Canyon without side trips

Tags: buses, tours, los-angeles, grand-canyon

I have been looking for bus tours that depart from Los Angeles to the Grand Canyon. I am interested to visit Las Vegas and the Hoover Dam on the way. Most of the tours that I found online include visits to shopping outlets / chocolate factory which are not interesting to me and tend to skip on actual sights like Hoover Dam or have reduced time at the Canyon. Do bus tours to the Grand Canyon from LA exist that avoid these side excursions? I am fine with a 2D/3N itinerary.

Comment: Welcome to TSE. Requests for recommendations or suggestions are not well-suited to our Q&A format; please take the site [tour] and review the [help] if you are new to Stack Exchange. I believe the question of whether tours without obligatory stops at tourist traps exist is valid, however, and have edited accordingly. You may roll back the change if I have misinterpreted the situation and you have a different on-topic question.

Comment: Los Angeles is 500 miles (800km) from the Grand Canyon. It seems natural that a journey like that would be broken up by side excursions, and a 2-day itinerary would be day 1: drive to Grand Canyon; day 2: drive back to Los Angeles. If you want a direct Grand Canyon inventory, it's probably better to start it somewhere closer and get to the start point under your own steam (e.g., by flying there).

Comment: Second that--the only way to do it at all would be to get on the bus in the evening and ride overnight both ways.  There's also the issue that the canyon isn't a full-day thing for most people.  It's simply not a logistically sensible trip.